# WSO2 IS - Federated Auth but use local claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IS 5.3.0 I am using a local SAML SP to talk to a federated SAML IDP (in testing, configuring two WSO2 IS servers, as described in https://medium.com/@dehami.deshan/configuring-federated-authentication-with-saml-sso-using-two-wso2-identity-servers-8dc0d3841a6b ).

I want the federated IDP to do the authentication but use the roles/claims from the local (WSO2) user store directly. Is there any configuration I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should add role and claim mapping in the federated IDP configuration.

Which basically means, mapping federated IDP's roles, claims to local roles/ claims

Please follow the **how to configure roles** section and **how to configure claims** in this doc for more information.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+and+Configuring+an+Identity+Provider

Comment: I am looking to simply use the roles/claim that are already present in in the local WSO2 user store already, not map anything from the Federated IDP (essentially ignore metadata from the Federated IDP). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use roles and claims in the local userstore, I presume that the user already exists in the local userstore also. Since you want to authenticate with federated IDP, you can do user account association between the local user and federated user and use the claims of the user.

To read more about associating user accounts in IS5.3.0, please follow this documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Associating+User+Accounts

After doing the account association, you can enable **Assert identity using mapped local subject identifier** (This option will use the local subject identifier when asserting the identity) under  **Local and Outbound Authentication Configuration** for the Service Provider. Please follow this documentation to configure that property under the service provider. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider